# Mudar Cor de Imagem ao clicar em botão

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho várias imagens, ao clicar no botão quero que ele pegue o ID da imagem passe esse ID para função OnChange e execute a função **update(this.jscolor)**.

Segue abaixo o trecho do código HTML completo:

```
<button name="color1" class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor)" 
   style="width:163px; height:46px; border:0px; margin:0px; padding:0px;"
   id="color_value" value="1085A9">
</button>
```

Comment: Pode adicionar o código html do formulário na pergunta?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe segue acima o código html

Comment: adicione o codigo do `update(color)`

Comment: você que esse input seja um botão cuja a única função é executar o onchange?

Comment: @Bia sim, isso mesmo.

Comment: Então voce tem algumas imagens, ao clicar nesse botão ele executa o onChange e troca a cor da imagem?

Comment: @Bia sim, isso mesmo. Como faço isso?

Comment: Você descreveu o processo todo no seu post, porque não tenta?

Comment: @GladisonNeuzaPerosini te atenderia se em cada imagem tivesse um checkbox, e para todos checkbox marcados ao clicar no botão a cor muda?